# Update angular-chart.js on filtered list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm fairly new to angular and I have come across a problem when adding angular charts js. I have a list that filters on a searchtext. My problem is that i want my charts to update each time i filter the list.

What would be a good approach to tackle this problem? I've tried to watch changes in the result (filteredresult below) of the list but i cant get it to work

```
<li ng-repeat="item in filteredresult = (result | filter:searchText)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add listener:

```
$scope.$watch('searchText',function(newValue,oldValue){
  //Some actions
})
```

Comment: I simplified my question a bit. I have 9 different filters that changes the list, one for each property in the list. And if i add a property to the list i would most likely add a filter to that as well. In that case I need to add a watch listener to each and everyone of my properties. Isn't there any better solution?